# jQuery resizeable column is not proper if increase table head more than 20?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with 40 columns. Jquery Resize is able will work properly on 10 columns but if I increase the number of columns then columns will overlap.

How to prevent this? Is there any CSS I can use or another jquery resize function which works properly.

Here is my code.

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tbl_AutoBidding").colResizable({
                    fixed: false,
                    liveDrag: true,
                    draggingClass: "dragging"
                });
            });
```

```css
table.gridMedium {background: #d2d2d2 !important;background-color: #d2d2d2 !important;border: 0px !important;}
        table.gridMedium tr td,
        div.gridMedium table tr td,
        table.gridMedium thead tr th,
        div.gridMedium table thead tr th {padding:2px !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-align:left;line-height:normal !important;}
    
        table.gridMedium tr th,
        div.gridMedium table tr th {
         background: #e0dfdf;
         
         }
         #dv_AutoBiddingtable table thead tr th, #dv_AutoBiddingtable table tbody tr td { white-space: nowrap !important; text-align: center; padding: 3px !important; }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Helper</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="small-12 columns" id="dv_AutoBiddingtable" style="overflow-x:auto">
            <table class="gridMedium" id="tbl_AutoBidding" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" border="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                        <th> LandMark Address </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    
            </table>
           
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/colresizable@1.6.0/colResizable-1.6.min.js" integrity="sha256-30OwSkLQCI3YsS9+88BMLSdDwa8AmswHozG45NpOmDA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any suggestion?
.........................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the initial width you have to add width attribute on every HTML th column(can **NOT** be done with CSS) e.g.

```
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
```

And to set the minimum width of a column when is opened, add `minwidth` option

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbl_AutoBidding").colResizable({
           fixed: false,
           minwidth: 100, //set the minimum width
           liveDrag: true,
           draggingClass: "dragging"
     });
});
```

Here is and working example of your snipped:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tbl_AutoBidding").colResizable({
                    fixed: false,
                    minwidth: 100,
                    liveDrag: true,
                    draggingClass: "dragging"
                });
            });
```

```css
table.gridMedium {background: #d2d2d2 !important;background-color: #d2d2d2 !important;border: 0px !important;}
        table.gridMedium tr td,
        div.gridMedium table tr td,
        table.gridMedium thead tr th,
        div.gridMedium table thead tr th {padding:2px !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-align:left;line-height:normal !important;}
    
        table.gridMedium tr th,
        div.gridMedium table tr th {
         background: #e0dfdf;
         
         }
         #dv_AutoBiddingtable table thead tr th, #dv_AutoBiddingtable table tbody tr td { white-space: nowrap !important; text-align: center; padding: 3px !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Helper</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="small-12 columns" id="dv_AutoBiddingtable" style="overflow-x:auto">
            <table class="gridMedium" id="tbl_AutoBidding" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" border="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
<th width="50px"> LandMark Address </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                        <td> LandMark Address </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    
            </table>
           
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/colresizable@1.6.0/colResizable-1.6.min.js" integrity="sha256-30OwSkLQCI3YsS9+88BMLSdDwa8AmswHozG45NpOmDA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: But Problem is that header overlap.. How to prevent header.

Comment: @MumbaiKandivali adjust the `<th width="50px">` to 100px or 200px every th can have it's own width

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. It works more than columns.

Added div element in th

```
<th><div>#</div></th>
```

1.for resize column

```
$("#thead_DispatchTrip th").resizable({
        handles: "e",
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.element).find('div').width(ui.size.width);
        }
    });
```